# I'm having trouble comparing two object elements that are strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, bubble-sort

I'm having trouble comparing two object elements that are strings and I'm pretty new still to Java. Can someone help me see what I am doing wrong here?
I am needing to sort by a specific object array element based on user input. I'm using a bubbleSort() method and running into issues with my comparisons. I have tried the compareTo() method and the compare() method. Here is my code for the sort method and notes on issues I'm having:

```
public static void bubbleSort(Event[] array)
{
//The prompt for a sort value needs to be in the loop too. I'm thinking a while loop, and maybe 
looking at using insertion sort instead of bubble. 
String[] SortValues = {"EVENT NUMBER", "EVENT TYPE", "TOTAL GUESTS"};
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int inputValue;
String sortValue;
//I have the bubbleSort method and inputEventType method as one. I think it would be better to 
separate them
System.out.print("Enter 999 at any time to exit sorting"); 
System.out.print("How would you like to sort the results?");
System.out.print("Please enter a number from the following: [0]Event Number, [1]Event Type, [2]Total 
Guests >> ");
inputValue = input.nextInt();
System.out.println();
    
int a, b;
int exitValue = 999; //I need to build a stop into the sorting code //somewhere...
Event temp;
//int comparisonsToMake = 7;
int comparisonsToMake = array.length - 1; //Maybe make this a //comparisonsToMake variable of 7 instead
char compareOneTwo = Character.compare(array[b].getEventNumber().chartAt(0), 
array[b+1].getEventNumber().charAt(0));
if(inputValue != exitValue)
    if(sortValues[inputValue].equals(sortValues[0]))  
        for(a = 0; a < comparisonsToMake; ++a)
            for(b = 0; b < comparisonsToMake; ++b)  
//maybe use the compareTo() method below, or possibly a //eventArray[].charAt(0)
                if(compareOneTwo > 0) //Issues here-EventDemo . java:30: //error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'Trying to compare the first //character of the event number string.
                {
                    temp = array[b];
                    array[b] = array[b+1];
                    array[b+1] = temp;
                }
    else if(sortValues[inputValue].equals(sortValues[1]))
                    for(a = 0; a < comparisonsToMake; ++a)
                        for(b = 0; b < comparisonsToMake; ++b)
                            if(array[b].getEventType() > array[b+1].getEventType())//And issues here- 
                            {
                                temp = array[b];
                                array[b] = array[b+1];
                                array[b+1] = temp;
                            }
    else if(sortValues[inputValue].equals(sortValues[2]))
                                for(a = 0; a < comparisonsToMake; ++a)
                                    for(b = 0; b < comparisonsToMake; ++b)
                                        if(array[b].getGuests() > array[b+1].getGuests())
                                        {
                                            temp = array[b];
                                            array[b] = array[b+1];
                                            array[b+1] = temp;
                                        }
```

}```

Comment: What type is the `eventType` attribute of an `Event`?  If it' not an `int`, `long`, `char`, `byte`, `short`, `float` or `double`, you can't use `<`, `<=`, `>=`  or`>` on it.

Comment: eventType is a String, as well as eventNum. You can see in my code I've tried to fix the bad operand error by pulling the first char of eventType and comparing it to the first char of the next objects eventType element, but my code must be off because I"m getting the "cannot find symbol" error on 

char compareOneTwo = Character.compare(array[b].getEventNumber().chartAt(0), 
array[b+1].getEventNumber().charAt(0));

Comment: I'm not sure why comparing characters would be a problem.  But you've also got `if(array[b].getEventType() > array[b+1].getEventType())...`, which is comparing two `String`s; you need to use  `if(array[b].getEventType().compareTo(array[b+1].getEventType()) > 0)...` for that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm not able to get the charAt() to work. I am getting the following error:
`EventDemo.java:28: error: variable b might not have been initialized
        String compareNumString1 = array[b].getEventNumber();`